# Prop not being passed to Child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is bizarre.  My console.log produces a company:

[image]

but for some reason in my child, when I try pulling it from props, it's null

**CompanyDetailContainer**

```
class CompanyDetailContainer extends Component {

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { fetchCompany } = this.props,
      { companyId } = this.props.match.params;
    await fetchCompany(companyId);
  }

  render(){
    const { company } = this.props;
    console.log(company) // this outputs a company
    return (
      <CompanyDetail className="ft-company-detail" company={company} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  company: state.company.company
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchCompany: fetchCompany
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(CompanyDetailContainer);
```

**CompanyDetail**

```
export default class CompanyDetail extends Component {
  render(){
    const callToAction = 'test';
      const { company } = this.props;

      console.log(company) // this is null!  why???  I've never had this problem before

      const title = `${company.name} Details`;
    return (
      <Main>
        <MainLayout title={title}>
          <div>
            <div id='ft-company-detail'>
              <div className="panel vertical-space">
                <CompanyHeader className="ft-company-header" company={company} />
                <div className="ft-call-to-action-interview">{callToAction}</div>
                <CompanyProfile className="ft-company-profile" company={company} />
                <RelatedLinks className="ft-company-resources" company={company} />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </MainLayout>
      </Main>
    );
  }
}
```

**///// UPDATE ////**

this worked:

```
 return (
       company &&  <CompanyDetail className="ft-company-detail" company={company} />
    );
```

But then why does this combo work fine?  it's setup pretty much the same way.  This is the first route hit on my app, renders this container:

**HomepageContainer**

```
class HomePageContainer extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.props.fetchFeaturedCompanies();
    await this.props.fetchCompanies();
    await this.props.fetchCountries();
  }

  render(){
    return (<HomePage
      className='ft-homepage'
      companies={this.props.companies}
      countries={this.props.countries}
      featuredCompanies={this.props.featuredCompanies}
    />);
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  countries: state.country.countries,
  companies: state.company.companies,
  featuredCompanies: state.company.featuredCompanies
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  fetchCountries: fetchCountries,
  fetchCompanies: fetchCompanies,
  fetchFeaturedCompanies: fetchFeaturedCompanies
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomePageContainer);
```

**HomePage**

```
export default class HomePage extends Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Main>
        <MainLayout title='Test'>
          <div className="homepage panel vertical-space margin-bottom-300">
            <FeaturedCompanies companies={this.props.featuredCompanies} />
            <div>
              <div className="column-group">
                <div className="all-100 width-100 align-center fw-300 extralarge">
              test
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <CompanyList className="ft-company-list" companies={this.props.companies} countries={this.props.countries}  />
          </div>
        </MainLayout>
      </Main>
    );
  }
}
```

To the fella who commented on my theme, the first image above is from Chrome tools dark theme.  Here is my actual theme in WebStorm which I think is even better :P:

[image]

Comment: componentDidMount is called after the render and your async call is in the componentDidMount, so for the first render the parent and the child both get null, and since you use `company.name` in child without a conditional check it errors out. Try to add a conditional check and see if it works

Comment: I have many more container / child setups like this and none of them have this issue

Comment: it worked.  But then why does my second example work? (updating my post to show another container / child combo that's setup exactly the same that works just fine)

Comment: see my update and question

Comment: Thats because you did perform a conditional check `if(!company) return null;
    const title = company.name + ' Test';`

Comment: that's a bad example let me update that. I have another that does not have that check, same setup and still works

Comment: ok check out my new example

Comment: `companies` should be an array, and the initialState should be an empty array. If you pass an array to a component and try to loop and show, and if it is an empty array, it will perfectly work fine. When the `companies` has values, (After `componentDidMount`) component will be rerendered with values. In case of single object, if it is `null`, it will fail.

Comment: It works because you are accessinganything from say companies , countries etc, if you do like companies.name it will also throw an error

Comment: Sorry off topic but what editor are you using? I like the colors.

Comment: Thx.  WebStorm / IntelliJ.  It’s my own custom theme...and there is a plug-in for JetBrains that can make the project pane’s background match my editor code background so that it looks very uniform throughout

Comment: actually you're not seeing my IDE you're seeing chrome dev tools dark version, console.  I'll post an example of my WebStorm theme too, see the update coming above

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri please post your answer and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: @PositiveGuy Ok great thanks. Did not know Chrome has a dark theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`componentDidMount` is called after the `render` and your `async call` is in the `componentDidMount`, so for the first render the parent and the child both get `null`, and since you use `company.name` in child without a conditional check it errors out. Provide a conditional check in the child and it will work fine

```
  const { company } = this.props;

  console.log(company)

  const title = company ? `${company.name} Details`: null;
```